# Void Binary Recursive Function that adds values. C

Tags: c, function, recursion, void, doubly-linked-list

I want to write a binary recursive function that adds all the data values in a doubly linked queue. It has to be a void function.

I have written the code below for a function which returns an integer value:

```
int add(Node * Front, Node * End)
{
    if(Front != Null)
    {
        if(Front == End)
             return front->data;

        if(Front->next == End) 
             return Front->data + end->data;

        Node * ptr1 = Front;
        Node * ptr2 = End;

        while (ptr1 != ptr2 && ptr1-> next != ptr2)
        {
             ptr1 = ptr1->next;
             ptr2 = ptr2->previous;
        }

        Node * mid = ptr1;
        return add(Front, mid) + add(mid->next, End)
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This is the struct of the nodes in the doubly linked queue:

```
 typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *previous;
 } Node;
```

I would like to know how the code should change if I were to add the values in the queue using a void function. Thank You! :)